# Dataclass to ignore attribute in asdict in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-dataclasses

I am creating a Python Tkinter MVC project using dataclasses and I would like to create widgets by iterating through the dictionary generated by the asdict method (when passed to the view, via the controller); however, there are attributes which I don't wish to include in the set of widgets. Before this edit I posted something similar to the class below (this is now more specific to the project I am working on, thanks to @Prune, @Cameron_McFee and @Brian_McCutchon for their responses). Is there a way to exclude attributes from the asdict method?  In the example below I don't want to include the 'customer' in the dictionary.

I tried, experimentally, including the two field specifications - repr=False and init=False on two of the fields but  I guessed they wouldn't work and they don't.

```
@dataclass
class Product:
    name: str
    description: str = field(repr=False)
    N: float = field(init=False, default=0.0)
    P: float
    K: float
    _customer = None #class variable until assigned
    self._customer # but 'self' doesn't exist in this context.

    @property
    def customer(self):
        return self._customer

    @customer.setter
    def customer(self, value):
        self._customer = value
```

I understand there are different ways to construct the class to achieve this, perhaps avoiding dataclasses, e.g:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, name: str, description: str, N: float, P: float, K: float):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.N = N
        self.P = P
        self.K = K
        self._customer = None 

    @property
    def customer(self):
        return self._customer

    @customer.setter
    def customer(self, value):
        self._customer = value
```

This involves more boilerplate which I would like to avoid if possible. An imperfect analogy would be a model in C# which can be instantiated using Dapper or EF.

Comment: Why are you asking us whether it's valid?  You should *know* before you post, since this is a testable item, and therefore out of scope for Stack Overflow.  "Pythonic" is opinionated, and also off-topic, unless you can point out a *specific* technique and explain your worries about that point.  Otherwise, you're asking for a code review -- on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#id7):

> The dataclass decorator examines the class to find fields. A field is defined as any variable identified in **annotations**. That is, a variable that has a type annotation. With two exceptions described below, none of the Data Class machinery examines the type specified in the annotation.

So it's valid python code but the `_dib` class variable (or the dib property) will not be included in the generated comparative methods as `_dib` is not in `__annotations__`

Comment: I think there's another problem: wouldn't `_dib` be a class variable in this case? Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: for sure, that's also problematic - but the getter should return the class variable None until the setter applies an instance variable in its place, right?  So it'll work like an instance variable with a default?